# Как узнать длину ключа объекта в js

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, frontend, backend

[image: Объект]
На изображении есть объект который я принимаю от сервера, а должен отобразить количество всех, в моем случае компаний, в Html документе, то есть число.
Как это сделать?

Comment: `data.list.length`

Comment: data is not defined

Comment: `data` была для примера, здесь должно было быть имя объекта который ты вывел сейчас на экран

Comment: в том то и дело, кроме того что я вывел на экран, я больше ничего не имею.
Есть только ссылка на сервер откуда я должен получать данные, когда перехожу по ссылке вижу ЭТО.

Comment: _На изображении есть объект который я принимаю от сервера_ - и _когда перехожу по ссылке вижу ЭТО_ так ты принимаешь объект, или только по ссылке переходишь?

Comment: @user8365703 Можно достать данные через `jQuery.getJSON()` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: В задании сказано: 
"При загрузке страницы получить данные компаний. http://test.test"
Показать общее количество компаний (отобразить в блоке)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.getJSON( "*ссылка на файл с объектом*", function( json ) {
  $('*селектор куда выводить число*').html(json.list.length);
 });
```

В теории как-то так. А как на практике, проверяйте.

В дополнение к комментарию.

```
$.getJSON( "http://codeit.pro/frontTestTask/company/getList", function( json ) {
    var out = '';
    var len = json.list.length;
        for(i=0;i<len;i++){
            out += '<p>' + json.list[i]['name'] + '</p>';
        }
    $('*селектор куда выводить список*').html(out);
});
```

Попробуйте так.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, а как теперь отсюда же вывести список этих компаний? тоже в html документ.

Comment: Могу дополнить в ответ.

Comment: Дополните пожалуйста, или как Вам лично написать?

Comment: Текущий ответ правильный, можно было так и оставить.

Comment: Оставил, так как из этого же объекта вывести списком все эти компании?

Comment: Все супер, только выводит не имена компаний а undefined

Comment: Попробуйте поиграть с кодом. Не имея json'a, в слепую писать код не могу.

Comment: http://codeit.pro/frontTestTask/company/getList
тут json файл

Comment: вроде готово, проверяйте

Comment: Все получилось, спасибо!